# How to create auto-scroll down effect with jquery & javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How to do an auto-scroll down effect with jquery and javascript?

```
<ul>
     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can implement bottom scroll with animation:

```js
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.bottom-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
     left: 50%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>
          <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>     <li><a >Beers</a></li>
     <li><a >Community</a></li>
     <li><a  >Shop</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="bottom-wrapper">
   <button>Scroll to botom</button>
   <div>
```

Comment: i mean when clicking on the community it's going to scroll down to the community section and so forth when addeventlistener